# Check whether sqlalchemy table is empty

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to know whether any given sqlalchemy table (sqlalchemy.schema.Table) has exactly 0 rows.  I have a lot of tables with a lot of rows in each and this has to run for all of them at startup so I am looking for the most efficient way to do this from a runtime perspective. So, just doing a count is not what I am looking for. The database is PostgreSQL if that changes anything

Comment: Do you need the actual count?  Or just if they have > 0?

Comment: @DavidS Just whether or not they are empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy will allow you to do a "raw" query.  In PostgreSQL, you can query the meta data for n_live_tup to get the record count:

```
SELECT 
  schemaname as schema_name,
  relname as table_name, 
  n_live_tup as record_count 
FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHERE n_live_tup > 0;
```

obviously, this gives you all of the tables with live records.  If you only want the ones without, change the to `WHERE n_live_tup = 0` and if you want to limit it to only a certain table add `table_name = <<your_table_name>>` to the where clause.

If you don't have a role with permissions, and you just want to see if the table is empty, then you can alway do this:

```
SELECT True FROM <<your_table_name>> LIMIT 1;
```

This will return True if the table has records or NULL if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The second approach is exactly what I am looking for. I was wondering however whether there was a way to do  that with only SQLAlchemy wrappers since raw SQL is a general no-no from a clean code perspective.

Comment: I've never understood the aversion to raw sql (after all, your ORM is going to generate it anyway), but for SQLAlchemy ORM then you would just use first().  According to the documentation, that does a limit 1.  If you get a object back, you have data in the table.

Answer (score 13):

You can use-

```
    db.query(Table_Name).first()
```

where `db` is `sessionmaker()` object. Thanks @David S